# Facing java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child

Tags: maven, java-17, tomcat10, spring-boot-3

I have recently updated my Spring Boot web application to Spring Boot 3 and jdk 1.8 to 17. However, when I try to run it on Tomcat 10, facing following error. However it is successfully running my Eclipse. I am facing this error is coming while deploying the webapp in the instance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alAbd.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVN9z.png)

same project is running fine with jdk 1.8 ,spring-boot 2.7.x in tomcat 9.x (before upgrade).

I am unable find what is the root cause of this error.

Thank you for help and appreciate any tip!